# javascript two ajax get requests one followed by the other

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I am trying to make two get requests to a DB using javascript, the first one allows me to grab a value from a db which decides the color of  a water tank, and the second one the level. I do this because data for temperature and level are placen on different databases, the problem is, however, that sometimes it seems the value coming from the first request doesn't seem to arrive on time and the color reverts to its default state. How can I make sure that the first request will be completed before the first, also during processing for the second request the tank is drawn, it's not that it exists and its attributes are being changed, its the whole thing that is updated every two seconds.

```
function drawTank2(){
      //la primera request se utiliza para cambiar el color del tanque de acuerdo a la temperatura
    var color="#0000ff";

     $.get('SearchDB',{action:'templatest'},function(responseText){     

         var array= new Object;

         array=responseText.split(',');

         temp=array[1];

         temp=parseInt(temp);


         finalcolor = temp*2;

         red=finalcolor;

         blue=255-finalcolor;

         red= Number(red).toString(16);

         blue=Number(blue).toString(16);

         red=red.toString();

         blue=blue.toString();

         color='#'+red+'00'+blue;


     });





//la segunda request grafica el tanque de acuerdo al valor de la variable nivel
       $.get('SearchDB',{action:'latest'},function(responseText){        

         var array= new Object;

         array=responseText.split(',');

         nivel=array[1];

         nivel=parseInt(nivel);


      show=nivel;

      level=-27*nivel/10+290;

      var lienzo = document.getElementById('myProgress');

      var ctx = lienzo.getContext('2d');

      ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,300);

      var my_gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
      my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"grey");
      my_gradient.addColorStop(1,"yellow");


      ctx.fillStyle=my_gradient;
      //contorno
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth="4";
      ctx.moveTo(40,90);
      ctx.lineTo(40,220);
      ctx.arc(110,220,70,Math.PI,Math.PI*2,true);
      ctx.lineTo(180,90);
      ctx.arc(110,90,70,0,Math.PI,true);
      ctx.fill();


      //lo llenamos según la variable nivel
      if(nivel<75){
       my_gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,100,0);
       my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"black");
       my_gradient.addColorStop(1,"#0000AA");     
      ctx.fillStyle=my_gradient;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(40,level);
      ctx.lineTo(40,220);
      ctx.arc(110,220,70,Math.PI,Math.PI*2,true);
      ctx.lineTo(180,level);
      ctx.lineTo(40,level);
      ctx.fill();
      }

      if(nivel<=100 && nivel>75){
          my_gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,100,0);
          my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"black");
          my_gradient.addColorStop(1,color);    
          ctx.fillStyle=my_gradient;
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(40,90);
          ctx.lineTo(40,220);
          ctx.arc(110,220,70,Math.PI,Math.PI*2,true);
          ctx.lineTo(180,90);

          var arco=Math.asin((90-level)/70);    

          ctx.arc(110,90,70,0,Math.PI*2-arco,true); 
          ctx.lineTo(110-70*Math.cos(arco),level);


          ctx.arc(110,90,70,Math.PI,Math.PI+arco);
        //  ctx.lineTo(190,29);*/
          ctx.fill(); 

      }


      //coloración de los tubos
      var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
      grd.addColorStop(0,"grey");
      grd.addColorStop(1,"white");

      //entrada
      ctx.fillStyle=grd;
      ctx.fillRect(85,10,50,15);
      ctx.fillRect(100,0,20,25);
      //salida
      grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,300,0);
      grd.addColorStop(0,"black");
      grd.addColorStop(1,"white");
      ctx.fillStyle=grd;
      ctx.fillRect(180,150,15,60);
      ctx.fillRect(195,135,12,90);

      //titulo
      ctx.fillStyle='rgb(0,0,0)';
      ctx.font="18px Arial";
      ctx.fillText("Nivel",140,20);

      //linea vertical de nivel
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(10,20);
      ctx.lineTo(10,290);
      ctx.stroke();

      //escala


      ctx.font="12px Arial";
     // ctx.fillText("0",12,290);
      //ctx.fillText("100",12,20);

      for(var i=0;i<11;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        var y=290-27*i;  
        ctx.moveTo(5,y);
        n=(i*10).toString();
        ctx.fillText(n,16,y);
        ctx.lineTo(15,y);
        ctx.stroke(); 
      }


 });   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the second request in the callback of the first:

```
$.get('SearchDB', {action: 'templatest'}, function(responseText) { 
    //...
    $.get('SearchDB', {action:'latest'}, function(responseText) { 
        //...
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, this has to be the quickest solution I have ever gotten in this website. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "ajax/example.php",
    data: 'page='+btn_page,
    success: function(data){
        $.ajax({
            var a=data; //edit data here
            type: "post",
            url: "example.php",
            data: 'page='+a,
            success: function(data){

      });
      error: function(data, errorThrown)
      {
          alert('request failed :'+errorThrown);
      }
});
```

I would ajax and do `error` function in it - just to make sure everything works and check where you get error.